# The residue of $\sin \left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$ around $1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I've tried to expand the function by first using the standard expansion of sinx and then plugging in $x = \frac{z}{z-1}$. The answer is supposed to be $\operatorname{Res}(1) = \cos 1$.

Comment: This function has an essential singularity at $z=1$. I am not sure the residue is even _defined_.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen The residue is defined in all isolated singularities, it's $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z-z_0\rvert = \varepsilon} f(z)\,dz,$$ where $\varepsilon > 0$ is so small that no other singularity is in the disk. It is usually computed by the Laurent expansion, where it is the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Um, right. I must be suffering from a shortage of caffeine. I was seeing _poles_ accumulating at this point, but they're only _zeros_, of course. I'll go get a cup right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin \frac{z}{z-1} = \sin \left(1 + \frac{1}{z-1}\right) = \cos 1\cdot\sin \frac{1}{z-1} + \sin 1\cdot \cos \frac{1}{z-1}$$

$\cos$ is even, hence the residue of the second summand is $0$, and only the residue of the first needs to be computed.

Comment: How did you get sin (z/(z-1)) = sin(1 + 1/(z-1))? Some trigonometric formula I should know?

Comment: That's just $$\frac{z}{z-1} = \frac{(z-1)+1}{z-1} = 1+\frac{1}{z-1}.$$ The trigonometric formula (addition theorem) starts after that.

Comment: Sometimes it's too simple! Thank you.